# SQL Server 2008 - Go From Select to Edit Quickly

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

In server management studio 2008 you can right mouse click on a table and then hit the select the first 1000 rows.  Is there a button or a quick way to edit one of the returned rows instead of having to right mouse click on the table again and click edit first 200 rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the way I normally go about this:

1. Right-Click table and select "Edit Top 200 Rows"
2. Right-Click anywhere on the results, navigate to Pane -> SQL

You'll see a SELECT statement that begins with

```
SELECT TOP(200) .....
```

Change the "200" to a larger value, or add a WHERE clause at the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

In Options - SQL Server Object Explorer, Commands you can edit the Values for the

Edit Top  Rows command

Select Top  Rows command

You could change the edit to be 1000 rows instead of 200

Answer (score 1):

On my system I can click on edit top 200 rows immediately (no initial select first 1000 required).

If you need to choose **Which** row, you can click on the SQL toolbar button to edit your query.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not helpful at all. "the SQL toolbar button"?

Comment: He means the "SQL" button on the toolbar that lets you select and unselect which panes are present in the current window.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, you may want to change the default settings to allow you to edit more than the 200 rows at a time, or select more than 1000 rows, which are the default settings for SQL Server.

To modify "Edit Top 200 Rows" or "Select Top 1000 Rows" setttings do the following:

1.In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, go to "Tools" -> "Options" -> "SQL Server Object Explorer" -> "Commands".

2.Now in the right-hand side "Table and View Options" section, you can change either: 
◦Value for Edit TopRows command, to a value greater than or less than 200.
◦Value for Select TopRows command, to a value greater than or less than 1000.

3.By specifying a value of 0, SQL Server will return all rows.  (If you sql tables are really large, you will definitely NOT want to set these values to 0.

4.Click OK to save your changes.